# Third party cookies not stored in IE 9.0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, xss

I'm using xss and sending parameters from domain1.com to domain2.com

Something like `i.src='domain2.com/xss.php?parameter=value'`

But when the xss.php is trying to store cookies for (self) domain2.com itself, it does not store in Internet Explorer (ver. 9.0). Works in other browsers. Is there a way to get around this problem?

In domain1.com/index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    i.src='domain2.com/xss.php?p=value';
</script>
```

In domain2.com/xss.php

```
$val = $_GET['p'];
setcookie('uid', $val, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/', 'domain2.com');
```

Comment: Post the relevant code and more details.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9.0 @JanHančič code is posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the privacy settings of IE if you set to "Medium", it turns on "Restrict First-party cookies that save information that can be used to contact you without your implicit consent" - If this is **ON**, cookies are not stored. Or else the cookies are stored.